# Sort Ascending or Descending inside a Bubble-Sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, return-value, bubble-sort

After [this was answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855527/bubble-sort-with-2d-array) I continued to work my way through the code. 
It work's perfect this way:

```
static String[][] bubbleSort(String customerdata[][], int sortafter, int asc)
 {
    String temp [];
    boolean sort;

        do{
             sortiert = true;

             for (int i = 0  ; i < customerdata.length - 1; i++){
                 if(customerdata[i][sortafter].compareTo(customerdata[i+1][sortafter]) < 0){
                     temp = customerdata[i];
                     customerdata[i] = customerdata[i+1];
                     customerdata[i+1] = temp;

                     sort = false;
                 }
             }

         }while(!sort);

  return customerdata;
 }
```

But as you can see, I'm missing int asc inside this function. What I want is to additionaly return a sorted descending or ascending array (depending wether asc == 1 (asc), or asc == 0 (desc)).

I'm at loss how to implement it inside this. I mean currently I can sort it ascending or descending, but once AFTER this method was called with some nasty long for() and if() loops.

I'd like to have it compactly inside and depending wether I give bubblesort(x,0,0) or (x,0,1) the list should be returned descending or ascending.

Comment: add the homework tag, or quit programming. Bubble sort is not something serious, unless for school experiments

Comment: It's not necessarily homework, he could be self-studying. Also, there's only room for 5 tags. We all know bubblesort is terrible, now let's try to learn something anyway!

Comment: What's your problem Bozho? Let me guess, you were born a pro-grammer?

Comment: No, but when I was doing bubble-sort, I was reading tutorials and understanding them, instead of wasting others' time.

Comment: Like I said, you apparently were born pro-grammer. How about this: Stop wasting my time and don't read stuff you don't like? Nothing helpful so far from you, compared to the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted ascending means the element at `i` is less than the element at `i + 1`.  Sorted descending means the element at `i` is greater than the element at `i +`.  The trick is to flip the logic where you decide whether the elements are out of place.  Specifically, this line:

```
if(customerdata[i][sortafter].compareTo(customerdata[i+1][sortafter]) < 0){
```

should be changed to

```
if(customerdata[i][sortafter].compareTo(customerdata[i+1][sortafter]) > 0){
```

if you want to flip the order of the sorting.

Comment: he's asking how he can add this into the code, conditionally of the parameter...  He already knows how to change the sorting

Comment: Yea, well, this answered my question. Can be solved with if(asc == 0) and else inside the do loop. Efficient? Not really. Works? Heck yeah!

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution: Can you make `asc` into one of `1` or `-1` ?

Then you'd only need to change one line:

```
if(asc * customerdata[i][sortafter].compareTo(customerdata[i+1][sortafter]) < 0)
```

Comment: Now that's the easiest way I. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can always sort ascending and simply reverse it if descending is required.  It's a question of whether or not repeating the "if" test inside the loop is less efficient that another traversal of the array.

I'm assuming that the size of the array is relatively small.  Bubble sort is notoriously inefficient and shouldn't be used except for small arrays.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware just how inefficient bubblesort is, nevertheless I'm still learning Java and its not my habit to skipe a few chapters just because they are inefficient. Either way I want to understand how this works.

Comment: Just for the record, I think that even with BubbleSort, your code is less horrible than some "professional" code I've seen on the operating table here :) I would ask you, though, to replace the leading tabs with (say) 2 spaces for easier reading.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 for (int i = 0  ; i < customerdata.length - 1; i++){
      if(customerdata[i+asc][sortafter].compareTo(customerdata[i+1-asc][sortafter]) < 0){
           temp = customerdata[i];
           customerdata[i] = customerdata[i+1];
           customerdata[i+1] = temp;

           sort = false;
      }
 }
```

Asc can be 0 or 1 (ascending or descending...)

by adding it to your index, you basically swap the if statement, without adding another if ;^)

(note there are 2 positions which I changed:  the "+ asc" and the "- asc")

EDIT:
Don't forget to put a big assert at the first line making sure Asc can really not be anything else than 0 or 1 ;^)

Comment: Yea, asert would be a good idea, also exceptions try n catch too. If a user should type in something else besides 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

And if you want the "software engineering" type answer instead of the quick hack answer I gave above, you can pass a functor (search for the Comparator class) to do the comparison, to allow for ultimately flexible searching.